# Saving the "view data options" in the "edit data" window in pgAdmin III

Tags: pgadmin

I wonder whether there is any way to save the "view data options" in the "edit data" window in pgAdmin III:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's annoying to have to input them again each time one opens a new "edit data" window.

Comment: I think this not possible in pgAdmin III, you can create a View, or Save the Query (Last n Querys automatically saved in the drop-down menu (Query-tool), or [Query Macros](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.22/macros.html)

Comment: No, it is not possible. You are wasted in MIT - you really should consider a career in software testing! :-)

Comment: @Vérace No worries, research papers are just as buggy and incomplete as computer programs :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people said in the comments, it is not possible. I didn't create a feature request for this as I feel it is going to be rejected (got some previous [negative](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/143171/9622) experience proposing features there), but if you want to try: https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin3